# How fast is computing a hash?

Tags: hash, time-complexity

Is it done in O(1) or O(n) or somewhere in between? Is there any disadvantage to computing the hash of a very large object vs a small one? If it matters, I'm using Python.

Comment: Depends on implementation of hash function.

Comment: One addon: Is there a higher chance of collision with larger objects vs smaller ones?

Comment: Well, my response would still be the same, collisions are algorithm dependent. You might have a string 100 character long, another just 1 character long. Now if your hash function takes into account the only the first character of the string you'll have a lots of collisions.

Comment: Is the question about cryptographic hash functions or other types such as those used in dictionaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, computing a hash will be O(1) for "small" items and O(N) for "large" items (where "N" denotes the size of an item's key). The precise dividing line between small and large varies, but is typically somewhere in the general vicinity of the size of a register (e.g., 32 bits on a 32-bit machine, 64 bits on a 64-bit machine). This can also depend on the input type--for example, integer types up on the register size all hashing with constant complexity, but strings taking time proportional to the size in bytes, right down to a single character (i.e., a two-character string taking roughly twice the time of a single character string).

Once you've computed the hash, accessing the hash table has expected constant complexity, but can be as bad as O(N) in the worst case (but this is a different "N"--the number of items inserted in the table, not the size of an individual key).

Comment: Asymptotic complexity might not be the most appropriate tool to use to discuss the running time with small input sizes, as it technically only cares what happens as we approach infinity. Also, can't you just say it's something like O(N/32) or O(N/64) (= O(N)) all the way from N=1? Perhaps more importantly, the complexity will fully depend on how you actually compute the hash - I don't imagine there's a rule stating you may only do O(1) work per byte to compute a hash.

Comment: Thanks. On a somewhat related note, does this mean a one-character string takes up 64 bits, and a two-character string takes up 128 bits? (assuming a 64-bit machine)

Comment: @Vic: No--typically a character will occupy something like one to four bytes, but any larger than that would be exceedingly rare.

Comment: @Dukeling: There are lots of things you could do, of course. Regardless of the notation you use, it seems like some people care that (for example) 1 and 100000000 will typically take the same time to hash, but "abcd" will take around four times as long to hash as "a" does.

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is it depends. You didn't specify what hash function you are interested in. When we are talking about cryptographic hash like SHA256, then complexity is O(n). When we are talking about hash function that take last two digits of phone number, then it will be O(1). Hash functions that are used in hash tables tend to be optimized for speed and thus are closer to O(1).

For further reference on hash tables see this page from python wiki on [Time Complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time your hash is going to compute in access at O(1). However, if it is a really bad hash where every value has the same hash, it will be O(n) worst case.

The more objects associated to the hash is equivalent to more collisions.